# "andern" vs "anderen"

Tags: word-usage, usage, reference-request

The citation below is the Duden's definition of [*vorausfahren*](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/vorausfahren) (my emphasis):

> schon vorher, früher als ein anderer oder vor [einem] **andern** her
> irgendwohin fahren

When I search online for the usage of *andern*, I find a variety of opinions, including that it is simply wrong, or that it is a colloquial (*umgangsprachlich*) variant of *anderen*.

This is fine from a *descriptive* point of view, but I wonder what the *normative* position/s is/are on this question.  (The fact that the source of the citation is a *dictionary word definition* [and not, say, a tweet], and that this dictionary is no lesser authority than the Duden, leads me to suspect that their choice of *andern* over *anderen* was *not* that the editors figured "colloquial" was the right register for this definition.)

So, to be specific: What is/are the authoritative reference work/s that I could consult to learn more about the *andern* vs *anderen* question?

Comment: The same contraction happens in a number of other words with *-ere-*, for example, *unsern* instead of *unseren*. I don't know if "colloquial" applies, but I think the *-ern* version is used more often in spoken German, and when spoken German is recorded in writing.

Comment: I'm surprised to see it written like this in the Duden, but they do indeed list it as a valid form: "die, keine, alle and[e]ren, andern" (https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/andere). As @RDBury said, in writing it's mostly used to evoke spoken German, but this may be changing. Language evolution, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

### Wiktionary

A good resource is wiktionary:

- [andern](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/andern)
- [anderen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/anderen)

It lists *»anderen«, »andern«* and *»andren«* as *Nebenformen* (in English: *variant*) of each other, which mean, all three form are correct and mean the same. But there is no distinct entry for *»andren«.* This means, that it is not used very often.

---

### Google ngram viewer

If you want to find out how the frequency of the usage of a word in printed books developed over the last 300 years, you should consult the [Google ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=andren%2Canderen%2Candern&year_start=1700&year_end=2019&corpus=31&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Candren%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canderen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Candern%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Candren%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canderen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Candern%3B%2Cc0). It gives you a diagram like this here:

[image: Google ngram: andren, anderen, andern]

So, you can see, that *»andern«* was the dominant form before 1870. Since then *»anderen«* is dominant. The form *»andren«* was always less important, but it also existed and was used all the time.

---

### DWDS

DWDS (»Digitales Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache«) allows you to search for word forms in a big collection of German texts, but the corpus of DWDS begins in the years 1900 and ends in the year 1999, so you only can find examples of how to use the word in texts from 20<sup>th</sup> century. When it finds a word in the corpus, it tells you how often the word exists.

- [anderen](https://www.dwds.de/r/?q=anderen&corpus=kern&date-start=1900&date-end=1999&genre=Belletristik&genre=Wissenschaft&genre=Gebrauchsliteratur&genre=Zeitung&format=full&sort=date_desc&limit=50)
  114037 displayable hits (132352 total)<sup>1</sup>
- [andern](https://www.dwds.de/r/?q=andern&corpus=kern&date-start=1900&date-end=1999&genre=Belletristik&genre=Wissenschaft&genre=Gebrauchsliteratur&genre=Zeitung&format=full&sort=date_desc&limit=50)
  15952 displayable hits (17817 total)<sup>1</sup>
- [andren](https://www.dwds.de/r/?q=andren&corpus=kern&date-start=1900&date-end=1999&genre=Belletristik&genre=Wissenschaft&genre=Gebrauchsliteratur&genre=Zeitung&format=full&sort=date_desc&limit=50)
  147 displayable hits (196 total)<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup> <sub>For copyright reasons, not all hits are displayable</sub>

So, DWDS tells you, that in 20<sup>th</sup> century the form *»anderen«* was more frequently used than *»andern«,* and that *»andren«* was used really rarely, but still, it was used.

But notice, that both tools, DWDS and Google ngram Viewer, can only search in printed texts. The frequencies found in printed texts may be different from the frequencies in spoken German.