# What does *her* add to the meaning of this sentence?

Tags: translation, word-usage, german-to-english, reference-request

(**NB:** If this question starts out looking very familiar to you, this is because it is in fact my *second* question about the same snippet of text.  The first one is this one: ["andern" vs "anderen"](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/65048/1890) .)

---

The citation below is the Duden's definition of [*vorausfahren*](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/vorausfahren) (my emphasis):

> schon vorher, früher als ein anderer oder vor [einem] andern ***her***
> irgendwohin fahren

**Q**:  What exactly does the highlighted ***her*** add to the meaning of the sentence above?  In other words, what effect would it have to omit it?

(PS: Any ***reference work*** that you may be able cite in support of your answer would be much appreciated.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Vor einem anderen her fahren* means "to drive in front of somebody", typically leading the way. *Vor einem anderen [irgendwohin] fahren* is typically understood to mean a temporal "before". So if I say

> Ich fahre vor Paul her nach Rom.

That means that I lead the way to our destination Rome and he drives right behind me.

> Ich fahre vor Paul nach Rom.

That means I drive to Rome before Paul does. Maybe we meet there, but maybe he only goes there weeks later.